# iOS horizontal scrollview with buttons using auto layout

Tags: ios

Im building a horizontal scrollview with buttons that are made programmatically (see code below). Now i want some spacing between the buttons in what i normally use auto layout.

```
int x = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 14; i++) {        
    UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc]  initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, 0, 10, self.soundBar.frame.size.height)];
    [button setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Button %d", i] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    [button sizeToFit];
    [[self soundBar] addSubview:button];

    x += button.frame.size.width;
}

[[self soundBar] setContentSize:CGSizeMake(x, self.soundBar.frame.size.height)];
```

How can i get left spacing between those buttons. And am i using the right approach to do this?

Comment: Looks ok, what's the issue?  Personally would probably add auto layout constraints programmatically.

Comment: The problem is that i cant reach my patent button right?

Comment: @KevinRietveld added an answer for the spacing with the string length and padding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the string size as per your data and add padding to that string for spacing.

```
int x=0;
for (int i=0; i<14; i++)
    {
        UIButton *btn=[[UIButton alloc]init];
        btn.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"yourfontname" size:15];
        [btn setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Button %d", i] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        CGSize stringsize = [btn.title sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"yourfontname" size:15]];
        btn.tag = i;
        [btn setFrame:CGRectMake(x,0,stringsize.width+30, 45)];
        x = x + stringsize.width + 30;
        [self.scrollView addSubview:btn];
}
```

Replacement of `sizeWithFont`:

```
CGSize size = [string sizeWithAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15.0f]}];
```

Comment: Thanks works very well needed to change some code because of deprecated functions.

Comment: @KevinRietveld yes `sizeWithFont` is deprecated you have to use other method. I am updating answer. If it helps to you just accept the answer like as http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work